# meaning of the adjective "unlikely" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course Media Literacy](https://youtu.be/oXf0F4GYzWQ). It is at 4 minute and 52 second. Here is the context:

> Suddenly, anyone, even an **unlikely** street kid without two pennies to rub together, could be in the know and feel like they were the king of the world.

I am aware of what the adjective means, but I cannot get what it means there. Dictionaries say that *improbable* is a synonim to *unlikely*. How could a kid be unlikely or improbable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that adjectival usage, **unlikely** means "one we would not expect" or "one who would not typically come to mind in this context".

> Basketball player Dennis Rodman, an unlikely ambassador, met with the North Korean dictator.

Comment: So that means that the kid who didn't have enough money to get a newspaper, actually would get it, am I right?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I interpret it as meaning *a street kid with unexpected knowledge*. (I get "knowledge" from "in the know.")

Comment: Some stereotypical street kid who is not likely to be "in the know" about something-- whatever  knowledge was being referred to in that Crash Course. I did not listen to it.  The conditions of the improbability are defined by the context.

Answer (score 0):

It's linking *unlikely* to *being in the know and feeling like they were the king of the world*.

The street kid without two pennies to rub together would otherwise be unlikely to be and feel those ways except that [whatever happened suddenly] happened, and so now the kid does.

It's similar to the common phrase *a likely story*, meaning an excuse that happens to conveniently, exactly apply to a situation which would otherwise have consequences for the person telling the story:

> A: How did you come into possession of all of those electronics?
>
> B: I was just walking along the street and then saw them fall off of the back of a passing truck.
>
> A: A likely story. [indicating that A does not believe that what B said is true]